# How to use scanner hasNext() to loop through a line of keyboard text and validate the user input of interger and string

Tags: java, keyboard, java.util.scanner

I am having a problem trying to understand how I can loop through a keyboard input line of text the user will give ex:

Anika 14 Dan 16

I want to read each token and assign to String name, Int, age, String name, int age. in that order.
This is easy however, if the user enters 
Anika Anika Anika Anika 13 13 13 Dan 16

Then I want the program to:

```
Anika, 
Integer needed got String, 
Integer needed got String, 
Integer needed got String, 
13, 
String needed got Integer, 
String needed got Integer, 
Dan, 
16
```

So first one will always be a string which is a word EDIT: "word", second an int and thrid string which is a "word" and fourth int. 
However, I can not simulate this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = null;
int age = 0;
String name2= null;
int age2= 0;
                if(scan.hasNext() == true)
        name = scan.next();
            age = scan.nextInt();
        name2= scan.next();
            age2= scan.nextInt();
```

I know if I do the top I get the right order, but it is the extra inputs that I would like to ignore but write a statement expression why it's wrong and then continue to search for the next int, or third string and so on.

```
 boolean isstring = false;
  boolean isnumber = false;
    do {
    if (scan.hasNext())
    {
        name = scan.next();
        isstring = true;
    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Need String got Integer");
        isstring = false;
        scan.next();

    }
    } while (!isstring);


    do {
    if (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        age = scan.nextInt();
        isnumber=true;
    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Need Integer got String");
        isnumber=false;
        scan.nextInt();

    }
    } while (!isnumber);



    do {
    if (scan.hasNext())
    {
        name2 = scan.next();
        isstring = true;
    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Need String got Integer");
        isstring = false;
        scan.next();

    }
    } while (!isstring);


    do {
    if (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        age2 = scan.nextInt();
        isnumber = true;
    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Need Integer got String");
        isnumber=false;
        scan.nextInt();

    }
    } while (!isnumber);


    }
```

I tried to use do while with ifs and It didnt work. My logic is wrong somewhere, and I think it might be the has.next() method.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: In second loop, when `hasNextInt()` returns false, you still call `nextInt()`, which will of course throw `InputMismatchException` exception. Call `next()` in the `else` clause to read and discard the non-integer token.

Comment: In the first loop, `hasNext()` will only ever return false if the input stream has been closed, so that doesn't happen. That's because even `13` *is* a string; it's a string of two digits. Did you maybe mean "word", not "string"? And how do you define a "word"? However you define it, *you* need to test that after calling `next()` to get the token. Get rid of the `hasNext()` check.

Comment: @andreas I tried it out but after the second loop, it doesn't do the validation anymore. You lost me after how to check for the word, should I do Interger,paserInt to see if the "string" is an integer?

Comment: If that's your definition of a "word", i.e. "not an integer". Is `2/14/2019` a "word"? Looks like a date to me. Is `3.14` a "word"? Looks like the PI number to me. As I said, you need to define what a "word" is, in order to re-prompt on anything that is not a "word".

Comment: Anika, what @Andreas is pointing out, is that sometimes, somethings can be Strings, but not "words". The validation process should be done previous to store/manipulate/uses this values, and to do this validation, you must define what is a valid word to your program. For the humans, when you call the variable "name", it's relatively clearly what you want, but not for the computer. Can a person be named "2/14/2019"? Or "-.-"? These are valid Strings. Take a look of string validation and regular expressions topics. Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is a word while waiting for an Integer, it will throw InputMismatchException. `nextInt()` first read the value as a String an then parse it as a Integer, so if you ignore the value using nextInt, if the value is a word, it will trow the aforementioned Exception.

### Using the same logic of your program

The changes should be:

1. Ignore the input with `scan.next()`
2. Check if a String can be or not an Integer (using `scan.hasNextInt()`), not if is a String, because any Integer can be expressed as a String.

```java
  boolean isstring = false;
  boolean isnumber = false;

  do {
   if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    isstring = true;
    name = scan.next();
   } else {
    isstring = false;
    System.out.println("Need String got Integer");
    scan.next();
   }
  } while (!isstring);

  do {
   if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    isnumber = true;
    age = scan.nextInt();
   } else {
    isnumber = false;
    System.out.println("Need Integer got String");
    scan.next();
   }
  } while (!isnumber);

  do {
   if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
    isstring = true;
    name2 = scan.next();
   } else {
    isstring = false;
    System.out.println("Need String got Integer");
    scan.next();
   }
  } while (!isstring);

  do {
   if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    isnumber = true;
    age2 = scan.nextInt();
   } else {
    isnumber = false;
    System.out.println("Need Integer got String");
    scan.next();
   }
  } while (!isnumber);
```

### Using try/catch and one loop

A naive solution using try/catch can be the following

```java
public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    String name = null;
    String name2 = null;
    Integer age = null;
    Integer age2 = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNext())
      {
    try
    {
      if (name == null)
        {
          System.out.println("Please provide name: ");
          name = getNameOrFail(scan);
          System.out.println("Name set: " + name);
        }
      if (age == null)
        {
          System.out.println("Please provide age: ");
          age = getAgeOrFail(scan);
          System.out.println("Age set: " + age);
        }
      if (name2 == null)
        {
          System.out.println("Please provide name2: ");
          name2 = getNameOrFail(scan);
          System.out.println("Name2 set: " + name2);
        }
      if (age2 == null)
        {
          System.out.println ("Please provide age2: ");
          age2 = getAgeOrFail (scan);
          System.out.println ("Age2 set: " + age2);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage ()); // Print the message put int Exception(message) constructor
      scan.nextLine(); // Flush the Scanner cache
    }
      }
  }

  public static String getNameOrFail(Scanner scan) throws Exception
  {
    if (scan.hasNextInt())
      throw new Exception("Need String got Integer");
    return scan.next();
  }

  public static Integer getAgeOrFail(Scanner scan) throws Exception
  {
    if (!scan.hasNextInt())
      throw new Exception("Need Integer got String");
    return scan.nextInt();
  }
```

Pay attention to the `scan.newLine()` in the catch clause, this is needed because the Scanner use a cache with the last input, so if is not re-read you enter in a infinite loop condition.

Good luck!

Comment: Ramons Merino also u mentioned the try catch and a one loop version of this, I was wondering if you can show me how? You dont have to since you already helped me out so much, just for learing I suppose, or maybe a psudo code so I can attempt it? Thank you regardless!

Comment: Of course, give me a moment to update the answer with more information.

Comment: Done! It can be improved in many ways, but I think points out the idea. Regards!